# How can we get value in php variable from javascript variable

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, variables

Can we get like this.
but i am not getting in php  variable.

```
<?php $n ?> = $(search1).size();
```

but i am getting like this

```
var n = $(search1).size();
alert(n);
```

please help me....

Comment: No, you cannot, you need to use AJAX. PHP is server side and JS is client side.

Comment: Looks like you have to learn a lot more about PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is processed on the server, before sending the result to the client.

For example, if you do this:

```
<p>
<?php
$name = "Dan";
print "hello, $name, ";
?>
How are you?
</p>
```

The client will get:

```
<p>hello, Dan, How are you?</p>
```

And then, the client will process any javascript included in the code.

So in your case, the server would try to process this code:

```
<?php $n ?>
```

and then send the result to the server, appending the code out of the  tags. Which would give an error, since $n by itself is not a valid php instruction.

So: PHP is executed on the server, and then, javascript is executed on the client.

You should check some tutorials, and try first to understand how PHP and Javascript work.

http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/php_tutorial_for_beginners/

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_introduction.htm